# Need help setting up OpenVPN on an Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

EDIT:

OK, thanks to all of your help I've made some progress. I fixed the connectivity issues with the bridge by manually setting up the bridge in the interfaces file and editing the bridge-start and bridge-stop scripts to only add/take-down the tap interface (See bellow for the current versions of these files.)

Now I can connect to the server, but the connection keeps getting dropped. Is this a key issue? I've tried regenerating the keys to no avail.

The log from Tunnelbrick when trying to connect to my server:

```
2010-09-19 10:08:05 *Tunnelblick: OS X 10.6.4; Tunnelblick 3.0 (build 1437); OpenVPN 2.1.1
2010-09-19 10:08:07 *Tunnelblick: Attempting connection with evan's apartment.conf; Set nameserver = 1; monitoring connection
2010-09-19 10:08:07 *Tunnelblick: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/openvpnstart start evan's\ apartment.conf 1338 1 0 0 0
2010-09-19 10:08:07 *Tunnelblick: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/openvpn --management-query-passwords --cd /Users/evan/Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Configurations --daemon --management-hold --management 127.0.0.1 1338 --config /Users/evan/Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Configurations/evan's apartment.conf --script-security 2 --up "/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/client.up.osx.sh" --down "/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/client.down.osx.sh" --up-restart
2010-09-19 10:08:07 SUCCESS: pid=2376
2010-09-19 10:08:07 SUCCESS: real-time state notification set to ON
2010-09-19 10:08:07 SUCCESS: real-time log notification set to ON
2010-09-19 10:08:07 OpenVPN 2.1.1 i386-apple-darwin10.2.0 [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Feb 24 2010
2010-09-19 10:08:07 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on 127.0.0.1:1338
2010-09-19 10:08:07  waiting...
2010-09-19 10:08:07 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from 127.0.0.1:1338
2010-09-19 10:08:07 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'pid'
2010-09-19 10:08:07 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
2010-09-19 10:08:07 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log on all'
2010-09-19 10:08:07 END
2010-09-19 10:08:07 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2010-09-19 10:08:07 SUCCESS: hold release succeeded
2010-09-19 10:08:07 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2010-09-19 10:08:07 Control Channel Authentication: using '/Users/evan/VPN/ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
2010-09-19 10:08:07 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2010-09-19 10:08:07 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2010-09-19 10:08:07 LZO compression initialized
2010-09-19 10:08:07 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:168 EF:68 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
2010-09-19 10:08:07 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
2010-09-19 10:08:07 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'e39a3273'
2010-09-19 10:08:07 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '3c14feac'
2010-09-19 10:08:07  or --up-delay
2010-09-19 10:08:07 Attempting to establish TCP connection with 192.168.0.2:1194 [nonblock]
2010-09-19 10:08:07 
2010-09-19 10:08:08 TCP connection established with 192.168.0.2:1194
2010-09-19 10:08:08 Socket Buffers: R=[525624->65536] S=[131768->65536]
2010-09-19 10:08:08 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
2010-09-19 10:08:08 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 192.168.0.2:1194
2010-09-19 10:08:08 
2010-09-19 10:08:08  restarting [0]
2010-09-19 10:08:08 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
2010-09-19 10:08:08  process restarting
2010-09-19 10:08:08 
2010-09-19 10:08:08 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2010-09-19 10:08:08 SUCCESS: hold release succeeded
2010-09-19 10:08:08 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2010-09-19 10:08:08 Re-using SSL/TLS context
2010-09-19 10:08:08 LZO compression initialized
2010-09-19 10:08:08 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:168 EF:68 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
2010-09-19 10:08:08 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
2010-09-19 10:08:08 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'e39a3273'
2010-09-19 10:08:08 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '3c14feac'
2010-09-19 10:08:08 Attempting to establish TCP connection with 192.168.0.2:1194 [nonblock]
2010-09-19 10:08:08 
2010-09-19 10:08:09 TCP connection established with 192.168.0.2:1194
2010-09-19 10:08:09 Socket Buffers: R=[525624->65536] S=[131768->65536]
2010-09-19 10:08:09 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
2010-09-19 10:08:09 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 192.168.0.2:1194
2010-09-19 10:08:09 
2010-09-19 10:08:09  restarting [0] ... (just keeps repeating from here)
```

Here are the updated files that I've changed:

interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

# Bridge for OpenVPN
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
bridge_ports eth0
```

bridge-start

```
#!/bin/bash

#################################
# Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux
# Requires: bridge-utils
#################################

# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth="eth0"
eth_ip="192.168.0.2"
eth_netmask="255.255.255.0"
eth_broadcast="192.168.0.255"
eth_gateway="192.168.0.1"
eth_network="192.168.0.0"

for t in $tap; do
    openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

#brctl addbr $br
#brctl addif $br $eth

for t in $tap; do
    brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
    ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
done

ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

#ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast gateway $eth_gateway
```

bridge-stop

```
#!/bin/bash

####################################
# Tear Down Ethernet bridge on Linux
####################################

# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged together
tap="tap0"

#ifconfig $br down
#brctl delbr $br

for t in $tap; do
    openvpn --rmtun --dev $t
done
```

My server.conf file look like the one aleroot suggested.

Thanks for all of your help so far, I think I'm close now :).

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm trying to get my Ubuntu 10.04 server to act as an OpenVPN server so I can eventually samba mount my data on my labtop while I'm at work. I've followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openvpn.html) a few times now with no luck.

I'm fairly certain the problem has to do with setting up the bridges and the tap interface. The reason I think that is because once I set up the bridge (using these scripts - http openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernetbridging.html#linuxscript  - sorry I can only make one link at the moment :)) and start the server (which starts with no errors) I'm loosing my eth0 connection ( and when I run ifconfig, only the new br0 has an IP address). Also after enabling the bridges I can no longer ssh to my server which starts working again when I stop the openvpn server and run the bridge-stop script.

I think I'm confused about which IP address goes where.

My router has public IP address, lets say it's 25.25.25.25 and my Ubuntu server has a static ip address of 192.168.0.2 (the port forwarding and everything works correctly, I can ssh in from anywhere, until I run the bridge scripts or try :)). Here are the values I've been using in the files specified above, do they look right?

From bridge-start (link to full file above)

```
# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth="eth0"
eth_ip="192.168.0.2"
eth_netmask="255.255.255.0"
eth_broadcast="192.168.0.255"
```

From server.conf

```
local 192.168.0.2
dev tap0
up "/etc/openvpn/up.sh br0"
down "/etc/openvpn/down.sh br0"
;server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
server-bridge 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.50 192.168.100
push "route 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1"
;push "dhcp-option DOMAIN example.com" <- commented not sure what i should use, the value is resolve.conf?
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
user nobody
group nogroup
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Instead of samba what about sshfs ?

Comment: @Chris, This is the first time I've heard about sshfs :), I'll look into it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can't really offer much on the configuration above, but I can suggest a couple of alternatives:

You might want to consider installing [OpenVPN-AS Server](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as.html) -- we run it on Ubuntu and it's great.  It installs quickly and painlessly, and has an intuitive web interface for configuration and monitoring.  It handles setting up the interfaces transparently and even configures appropriate iptables rules for you.  Up to 2 concurrent users are free, and more are cheap ($5/user/yr).  Clients can download a pre-configured, customized config file (*.nix) or setup package (Windows) from the web interface.

Alternatively, you could run [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) in a VM (runs great under KVM in Ubuntu) or put it on a separate box (it doesn't need much for hardware) and take advantage of the L2TP, OpenVPN, or PPTP VPN servers built in.  Again, this would take some of the pain out of the configuration and setup, though you would need to [set up KVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM) if you went that route.

Comment: Thanks! Next time I attempt something like this I'll look into it, but for now I'm committed to figuring this out :). I feel like I'm just missing something obvious and silly - like the missing semicolon when you're learning to program.

Comment: I appreciate tenacity.  Hope someone else here has a good suggestion for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use a bridge for what you want to do.  Have you tried just setting up a normal OpenVPN server?

Comment: No, though I also heard that was easier than doing it via bridging. The reason I didn't is that I'm under the impression it's easier to set up Samba a share inside a VPN when using bridging. Do you know if that's the case?

Answer (score 0):

An Example of Server.cfg in your situations :

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tap
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/Server-VPN.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/Server-VPN.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
server-bridge 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.50 192.168.0.100
push "route 192.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Also you need to run at system startup this script(insert it in /etc/init.d/ and symlink in /etc/rcX.d/ in your ubuntu distro ) for setting up your bridge:

```
#!/bin/bash

#################################
# Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux
# Requires: bridge-utils
#################################

# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth="eth0"
eth_ip="192.168.0.2"
eth_netmask="255.255.255.0"
eth_broadcast="192.168.0.255"

for t in $tap; do
    openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

brctl addbr $br
brctl addif $br $eth

for t in $tap; do
    brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
    ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
done

ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast
```

Comment: Thanks for throwing that together for me!! I went through it twice and I still can't get it working though - I think the problem is with the bridge. Using exactly that bridge start script above seems to mess with my ethernet connection. Before I run that script I can ssh into the server with the domain dyndns provided me, and after I can't anymore. If I run bridge-stop and the restart networking, I can SSH in again. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? (I can SSH to the server from inside the network by using ssh 192.168.0.2, just not when I use ssh my.dyndns.com).

Comment: Do you have installed bridge-utils ? if not try this from console : sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils

Comment: Yes, bridge-utils are installed.

Comment: Update: I also realized that after running the bridge-start script I cannot access the internet (via ping google). I tried to add the line 'eht_gateway="192.168.0.1"' but it didn't end up helping.